# Why isn't my decimal to binary converter working in python?

Tags: python, binary, decimal, converters

Here is my code:

```
dec=int(input("lol"))
a=[]
while dec>0:
    remainder=dec%2
    if remainder>0:
        a.append(1)
        dec=dec-remainder
    else:
        a.append(0)
        dec=dec-remainder
bn=''.join(str(e) for e in a)
bn=bn[::-1]
print(binary)
```

When run i type in the integer I wantand after that nothing comes up.

Comment: Can you fix the indentation?  (Here and in your actual code if there is a problem there)...

Comment: The indentations on my code are fine its just when I copied it to stack overflow they got weird

Comment: If it "got weird" it may be that you used tabs. :)

Comment: Feel free to upvote my answer since it contains your solution

Comment: The vote-to-close and question downvote are wrong, this is an on-topic question, with code, and the OP has show some effort.

Comment: I would love to upvote your answer howver my rep is only 8 and 15 is redquired

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Typo: your last line should surely be `print(bn)` instead of `print(binary)`

2) Loop hangs: you never do a rightshift `>>` /divide-by-two on dec, so **your loop never ends**.
Since you're going to do a shift, you don't need to explicitly subtract remainder, it will just get right-shifted off (see Note a).
You can do either of:

```
dec = dec >> 1
dec >>= 1 # too cryptic, since >> is a rare operator
```

2b) Bug: you need to **prepend**, rather than append, successive digits of `a` or `bn`.

Anyway here's a complete rewrite for compactness; we can dispense with list `a` and prepend the current directly to string `bn`, and we don't need an if-else clause:

```
dec=int(input("lol"))
bn = ""
while dec > 0:
    bn = str(dec % 2) + bn # prepend, not append!
    dec = dec >> 1

print(bn)
```

(It doesn't strip leading-zeros, but that's a trivial string/regex-replace job.)

Note a) by the way, subtracting remainder=0 in the `if remainder==0` clause was unnecessary. And anyway that `dec = dec - remainder` line could have been common-case code, not inside an if-else. So could `a.append(dec % 2)` ).

Comment: true how silly of me but ever after amending taht mistake it still does not work

Comment: May I ask what the >>1 does

Comment: `>>` is the rightshift operator (does an integer divide-by-two). See the doc [5.4.1. Bitwise Operations on Integer Types](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#bitwise-operations-on-integer-types)